# MySQL Cursor fetching only one row

Tags: mysql, sql, database-cursor

My SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INV_MIN_PURCHASE_PRICE()
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT;
DECLARE current_inventory_ID INT;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT inventory_ID FROM _inventory;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

SET done = 0;
OPEN cur1;

REPEAT

    FETCH cur1 INTO current_inventory_ID;
    UPDATE _debug SET rows=rows+1;

UNTIL done
END REPEAT;

CLOSE cur1;

END;
```

When I call this procedure MySQL is fetching only one row (_debug `rows` are increased by 1). Why?? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 16):

I just had the same problem with a stored procedure in MySQL. It was supposed to get all records from a table that have a null value in a certain column, and then fill that value from another table. However, it stopped after one record:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `updateRecord`()
    BEGIN

    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE recordId, newValue INT;
    DECLARE current_record CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM A where b_id is null;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE; 

    OPEN current_record;

    main_loop: LOOP
        FETCH current_record INTO recordId;

        IF done THEN
             LEAVE main_loop;
        END IF;

        -- fetching some value from table b
        select id into newValue from B where ...

       -- setting new value in record
       update A set b_id = newValue where id = recordId;    

      END LOOP;
    END
```

The answer is that the "handler for not found" is not only executed if the cursor returned no rows, but also if the select on table B returned no rows. My solution was to use a second variable that was set by the handler and reset the "done" variable after the select:

```
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE, noBfound = TRUE;    

           [...]

           select id into newValue from B where ...

           IF (noBfound = TRUE) THEN 
               SET done = FALSE;
           END IF;

           [...]
```

Addition: It's obviously possible to do without a second variable by simply resetting the "done" after the select:

```
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE; 

           [...]

           select id into newValue from B where ...

           SET done = FALSE;

           [...]
```

Comment: This is the correct approach: _Addition: It's obviously possible to do without a second variable by simply resetting the "done" after the select_. Clean and simple

Answer (score 1):

```
IF done THEN
         LEAVE main_loop;
ELSE
         ITERATE main_loop;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a LOOP instead of the REPEAT construct? Seems to work better in MySQL. Replace the REPEAT to END REPEAT section with:

```
inv_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO current_inventory_ID;
    IF done = 1 THEN
        LEAVE inv_loop;
    END IF;
    UPDATE _debug SET rows=rows+1;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: I tried this at first place (basing on example in MySQL docs). No success.

Comment: I'm assuming that if you just try SELECT inventory_id FROM _inventory in the MySQL console you get more than one row back, right?

Comment: Of course. I already fixed the problem. Updated my MySQL server to the newest version and now code works fine.